# Change Icon type inside a For loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a different amount of buttons for each user on my App, on this app I will store the data from the buttons inside documents in Firestore, this documents store what does that Buttons contain, so, the text, icon, label, etc. It will all be stored inside these documents. I have 1 document for each button. At the moment I'm working with 3 buttons, so I have 3 documents.
 I have created a For loop so I can create these buttons inside my App. But what I tried, was adding a List that will get all the icons name from my firestore, so I can insert in the loop.
This is the List I tried:

```
List<String> icondata = [for (int i = 0; i < cardamount; i++)  documents[i]["icondata"]];
```

What this list contains is the type of Icon, so:

```
[lock, lightbulb_outline, check]
```

What I tried to do in my loop was:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cardamount; i++)  
                                CustomCard(
                                  activeLabel: activelabel,
                                  inActiveLabel: inactivelabel,
                                  iconData: Icons.icondata[i],
                                  text: 'Lâmpada 2 Schuma',
                                  isActive: snapshot.data[devices[i]],
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document(user.uid).updateData({
                                        devices[i]: cardsValue[i] = !cardsValue[i],
                                      });
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
```

This is what I tried:

```
iconData: Icons.icondata[i],
```

But apparently I can't do that, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly do this, but you can use the following way:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = [
      {'name': 'Account Data', 'icon': 'account_balance'},
      {'name': 'Banker', 'icon': 'home'},
    ];
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
                runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
                children: data
                    .map((e) => Chip(
                          avatar: Icon(
                            getIconData(e['icon']),
                            size: 18,
                          ),
                          label: Text(e['name']),
                        ))
                    .toList())));
  }

  IconData getIconData(String name) {
    switch (name) {
      case "account_balance":
        return Icons.account_balance;
      case "home":
        return Icons.home;
    }
    return Icons.check_box_outline_blank;
  }
}
```

This code uses a switch-case statement to compare the string to known values and return the `Icon` object based on that.

Comment: But how am I going to implement this with the CustomCard that I have?

Comment: replace `iconData: Icons.icondata[i],` with `iconData: getIconData(icondata[i]),`

Comment: But instead of passing a String name, I will pass the name of the Icon? And, this is limited right, Because if I want to add a Icon, I will have to add a case right?

Comment: Yes, it's true. You need to keep the names

Comment: Is there a way that Instead of creating a IconData inside the class, I can create this as a function outside the class? If you could do that an Update the question I can check your as right

Comment: you can create a static class outside of your main UI pages and use it wherever you need it.